# GridView background when metro app is snapped

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, microsoft-metro

I have set the background color of my metro (windows store) app to be red, it works fine when the app si filled or fullscreen. But when I have app in snapped view the background color is default gray. How can I change it ?
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I havent understood your question very well, but if you means that your applications background dosent appear when align the window to right or left i will answer you:

Certainly you are using Visual Studio 2012 and windows 8, in VS 2012 there is a window named Device this window helps you to simulate your window modes press on desired mode and set the appropriate background

Comment: Finaly, I wasnt able to find out myself how to set the background when its snapped. Thanks a lot :)